# How do you create custom Event in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How do i create a customEvent Typescript and use it? I found this link on javascript on Mozilla site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

I am just doing some testing on custom Event but Typescript see it as an error. what i am planning on doing is add some extra data into the details property to use later: here is my code.

```
let div:any=document.getElementById("my_div");

let c_event = new CustomEvent("build",{'details':3 });

div.addEventListener("build",function(e:Event){
    console.log(e.details);
}.bind(this));

div.dispatchEvent(c_event);
```

Comment: what error do you see? that looks like valid js code thus most likely valid ts as well.

Comment: let c_event = new CustomEvent("build",{'details':3 }); should be let c_event = new CustomEvent("build",{detail:3 });

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The property name is `detail` and not `details`. The correct code needs to be:

```
let div: any = document.getElementById("my_div");

let c_event = new CustomEvent("build",{detail: 3});

div.addEventListener("build", function(e: CustomEvent) { // change here Event to CustomEvent
    console.log(e.detail);
}.bind(this));

div.dispatchEvent(c_event);
```

Comment: At first I thought this didn't work, but then i figured out that JSON.stringify() on a CustomEvent doesn't show the detail member ... sigh.

Comment: Seeing this: `has no properties in common with type 'CustomEventInit<unknown>'`

Comment: It worked for me, only when i defined the type of the event-parameter in the `addEventListener` as `CustomEventInit`

Comment: `CustomEvent` is a generic type, so in this example, with the type of `detail` being `number`, you can use `CustomEvent<number>`. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568282/685715

Comment: I don't know if this is something with TS version but CustomEvent won't work, CustomEventInit does as stated earlier, the generic being the type of your custom "detail".

Answer (score 41):

The solution described in the accepted answer gets the job done but for the cost of losing type safety.

**If you want to keep the type-safety** going I would suggest the following:

Create `dom.d.ts` file in `@types` folder in your sources (or configure [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) to make sure that TS compiler will look there) with the following:

```
interface CustomEventMap {
    "customnumberevent": CustomEvent<number>;
    "anothercustomevent": CustomEvent<CustomParams>;
}
declare global {
    interface Document { //adds definition to Document, but you can do the same with HTMLElement
        addEventListener<K extends keyof CustomEventMap>(type: K,
           listener: (this: Document, ev: CustomEventMap[K]) => void): void;
        dispatchEvent<K extends keyof CustomEventMap>(ev: CustomEventMap[K]): void;
    }
}
export { }; //keep that for TS compiler.
```

This will augment [global definition](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-augmenting-global-lib-dom/) of `document`'s `addEventListener` function to accept your synthetic event and its typed params.

now you can do:

```
function onCustomEvent(event: CustomEvent<CustomParams>){
  this.[...] // this is Document
  event.detail ... //is your CustomParams type.
}
document.addEventListener('anothercustomevent', onCustomEvent);
```

This way you will have everything typed and under control.

Comment: Three small changes for completeness sake. 
1) The `addEventListener` declaration should include the third `options` parameter: `options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions`.
2) The return type of the `listener` param should be `any` to match the one in lib.dom.d.ts
3) You should include the declaration for `removeEventListener` (including the above points): 
`removeEventListener<K extends keyof CustomEventMap>(
      type: K,
      listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: CustomEventMap[K]) => any,
      options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions,
    ): void;`

Comment: Also, if you move the `CustomEventMap` to the global definition, you don't have to redefine the params every time. You can then just use it like:

`const customHandler = (event: CustomEventMap['mycustomevent']) => console.log(event.detail.every.defined.prop.will.be.here)`

Comment: This was close to what I needed, but using GlobalEventHandlersEventMap was way shorter and needed no further definition. Found in this github comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28357#issuecomment-748550734

Answer (score 39):

Simplest way is like so:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", ((event: CustomEvent) => {
   console.log("Whoop!");
}) as EventListener);
```

Comment: this should be the go-to answer for many reasons

Comment: Could you elaborate? What are some of the many reasons that this should be the go-to answer?

Comment: @FlavioWuensche - Because it is much more brief than the top answer, and contains less irrelevant code than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 15):

`CustomEvent` is a generic type. You can pass the type of the `detail` property as a parameter (it defaults to `any`). Here is how it is defined in [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) (which is in the `lib` directory of your npm typescript installation):

```js
interface CustomEvent<T = any> extends Event {
    /**
     * Returns any custom data event was created with. Typically used for synthetic events.
     */
    readonly detail: T;
    initCustomEvent(typeArg: string, canBubbleArg: boolean, cancelableArg: boolean, detailArg: T): void;
}
```

In the OP's example, the type of `detail` is `number`. So, building on the answer from @Diullei:

```js
let div: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("my_div");

let c_event = new CustomEvent<number>("build", {detail: 3});

div.addEventListener("build", function(e: CustomEvent<number>) { // change here Event to CustomEvent
    console.log(e.detail);
}.bind(this));

div.dispatchEvent(c_event);
```

Above, I've also used the `HTMLElement` type from `lib.dom.d.ts`.
As a newcomer to TypeScript, I found it very useful to scan this file, and search it for 'obvious' types.

Comment: if you add index.d.ts to your root it picks up automatically in REACT.  I also added the declare CustomEvent and interface CustomEventInit

Comment: The link is 404 now. I have found https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/blob/29de1d981d83c2e99f6995c4e5fae934cd7d709a/baselines/audioworklet.generated.d.ts#L306 instead

Answer (score 4):

I ended up taking a different approach. Instead, I made a wrapper class that extended EventTarget.

```
type AudioEvent = {bytes: Uint8Array};

interface IAudioEventTarget {
  addListener(callback: (evt: CustomEvent<AudioEvent>) => void): void
  dispatch(event: AudioEvent): boolean;
  removeListener(callback: (evt: CustomEvent<AudioEvent>) => void): void
}

class AudioEventTarget extends EventTarget implements IAudioEventTarget {
  private readonly targetType = 'audio-event';

  addListener(callback: (evt: CustomEvent<AudioEvent>) => void): void {
    return this.addEventListener(this.targetType, callback as (evt: Event) => void);
  }

  dispatch(event: AudioEvent): boolean {
    return this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(this.targetType, { detail: event }));
  }

  removeListener(callback: (evt: CustomEvent<AudioEvent>) => void): void {
    return this.removeEventListener(this.targetType, callback as (evt: Event) => void);
  }
};
```

And usage is as follows:

```
const audioEventTarget = new AudioEventTarget();
const listener = (audioEvent: CustomEvent<AudioEvent>) => {
    console.log(`Received ${audioEvent.detail.bytes.length} bytes`);
}

audioEventTarget.addListener(listener);
audioEventTarget.dispatch({bytes: new Uint8Array(10)});
audioEventTarget.removeListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Jurijs Kovzels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4416181/jurijs-kovzels)' answer is technically correct - all you have to do is extend the global DOM types.

But the implementation is a bit tedious: you will have to extend type of `addEventListener()`, `removeEventListener()` and `dispatchEvent()` for all types of elements (`HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLDivElement`, etc.)

Instead, I'd suggest to

### Extend `GlobalEventHandlersEventMap`.

There are a couple of ways you can do it:

##### A) Declare it globally in a file of interest

This is a fast way to make sure everything works but I would not keep it in a production codebase.

```
declare global {
  interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
    build: CustomEvent<number>;
  }
}
```

##### B) Create your own `.d.ts` declaration file

You can do the same as above by writing your own file with global declarations

1. Create a file `declarations/dom.d.ts` and add the following in it

```
interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
  build: CustomEvent<number>;
}
```

2. Then make sure it is included in your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "include": [
    "declarations/*.d.ts",
  ],
}
```

3. And it works! Now your listeners are properly typed
   [image: typed-custom-event-listener]

You can go further and add util for creating strictly typed events like this:

```
export const createTypedCustomEvent = <T extends CustomEventType>(
  type: T,
  eventInitDict: CustomEventInit<CustomEventHandlersMap[T]>,
) => new CustomEvent(type, eventInitDict);
```

Then you will be getting type hints and checks for the `detail` field:

Non existent event
[image: typed-custom-event-key-error]

Incorrect type of event detail
[image: typed-custom-event-detail-type-error]

Answer (score 1):

maybe overly complicated but typesafe?

```
interface FizzInfo {
  amount: string;
}

interface BuzzInfo {
  level: number;
}

interface FizzBuzzEventMap {
  fizz: CustomEvent<FizzInfo>;
  buzz: CustomEvent<BuzzInfo>;
}

interface FizzerBuzzer extends EventTarget {
  addEventListener<K extends keyof FizzBuzzEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: FizzerBuzzer, ev: FizzBuzzEventMap[K]) => void, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
  addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
  removeEventListener<K extends keyof FizzBuzzEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: FizzerBuzzer, ev: FizzBuzzEventMap[K]) => void, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
  removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}

class FizzerBuzzer extends EventTarget {
  numFizz: number = 0;
  numBuzz: number = 0;

  start(): void {
    setInterval(() => this.emitFizz(), 3000);
    setInterval(() => this.emitBuzz(), 5000);
  }
  emitFizz(): void {
    ++this.numFizz;
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent<FizzInfo>('fizz', {
      detail: { amount: this.numFizz.toString() },
    }));
  }
  emitBuzz(): void {
    ++this.numBuzz;
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent<BuzzInfo>('buzz', {
      detail: { level: this.numBuzz },
    }));
  }
}


const fb = new FizzerBuzzer();
fb.addEventListener('fizz', (ev) => {
  console.assert(typeof ev.detail.amount === 'string', 'bad!');
  console.log(ev.detail.amount);
});
fb.addEventListener('buzz', (ev) => {
  console.assert(typeof ev.detail.level === 'number', 'bad');
  console.log(ev.detail.level);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Credits to @kirill-taletski

```
declare global {
    interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
        'your-custom-event-name': CustomEvent<{}>;
    }
}

export const createCustomEvent = <T extends keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap>(
    type: T,
    eventInitDict: CustomEventInit<
        GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[T] extends CustomEvent<infer T> ? T : never
    >,
) => new CustomEvent(type, eventInitDict);
```