# Create custom event within class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, events, event-handling

I am trying to figure out how to create a custom event for a class in TypeScript. Examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001679/how-do-you-create-custom-event-in-typescript) didn't help me much in understanding how to do that.

My example class looks like the following.

Cat.ts:

```
export class Cat {
    public getName(): string {
        return this.catName;
    }

    public setName(catName: string) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    constructor(private catName: string) { }

    public makeMeow() {
        this.onWillMeow();
        console.log("Cat meows!");
        this.onDidMeow();
    }

    public onWillMeow() {
        console.log("onWillMeow");
    }

    public onDidMeow() {
        console.log("onDidMeow");
    }
}
```

Now I would like to be able to declare events from outside like the following code aims to demonstrate.

```
const myCat: Cat = new Cat("Tikki");
myCat.onWillMeow({event => {
     console.log("Tikki the cat is just about to meow!");
}});
myCat.onWillMeow({event => {
     console.log("Tikki the cat did just meow!");
}});
myCat.makeMeow();
```

Now, I would imagine to get some output like this one:

```
onWillMeow
Tikki the cat is just about to meow!
Cat meows!
onDidMeow
Tikki the cat did just meow!
```

What do I have to do to make this work in TypeScript? How is this called exactly? Creating a ***custom event*** or creating a ***custom event handler***?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
type Handler<E> = (event: E) => void;

class EventDispatcher<E> { 
    private handlers: Handler<E>[] = [];
    fire(event: E) { 
        for (let h of this.handlers)
            h(event);
    }
    register(handler: Handler<E>) { 
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}

interface WillMeowEvent { }
interface DidMeowEvent { }

class Cat {
    public getName(): string {
        return this.catName;
    }

    public setName(catName: string) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    constructor(private catName: string) { }

    public makeMeow() {
        this.fireWillMeow({});
        console.log("Cat meows!");
        this.fireDidMeow({});
    }

    private willMeowDispatcher = new EventDispatcher<WillMeowEvent>();
    public onWillMeow(handler: Handler<WillMeowEvent>) {
        this.willMeowDispatcher.register(handler);
    }
    private fireWillMeow(event: WillMeowEvent) { 
        console.log("onWillMeow");
        this.willMeowDispatcher.fire(event);
    }

    private didMeowDispatcher = new EventDispatcher<DidMeowEvent>();
    public onDidMeow(handler: Handler<DidMeowEvent>) {
        this.didMeowDispatcher.register(handler);
    }
    private fireDidMeow(event: DidMeowEvent) { 
        console.log("onDidMeow");
        this.didMeowDispatcher.fire(event);
    }
}

const myCat: Cat = new Cat("Tikki");
myCat.onWillMeow(event => {
     console.log("Tikki the cat is just about to meow!");
});
myCat.onDidMeow(event => {
     console.log("Tikki the cat did just meow!");
});
myCat.makeMeow();
```

I'm sure there are libraries that can help.  Anyone want to recommend a library in another answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please evaluate the meaning between `type Handler<E> = (event: E) => void;`? Why point to `void`? The name `Handler` is just a name and could be anything, right?

Comment: The `void` means that the event handlers (for example, the function with `console.log("Tikki the cat is just about to meow!");`) do not return a value.  Indeed, `Handler` is just a name that could be changed, but it's a pretty standard term.

Comment: `I'm sure there are libraries that can help. Anyone want to recommend a library in another answer?`. Yes, and without simply giving a link, I have added a complete example of using [sub-events](https://github.com/vitaly-t/sub-events) to implement what was asked in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

When implementing custom events today, it is important that the event is strongly-typed, i.e. the type of data that the event sends is inferred during transpile time, to make the code less error-prone.

There are several libraries today that can do that. Here's is how you can do it with [sub-events](https://github.com/vitaly-t/sub-events):

```
import {SubEvent} from 'sub-events';

class Cat {

    // strongly-typed event that expects a string:
    readonly onMeow: SubEvent<string> = new SubEvent();

    constructor(private catName: string) {
    }

    public makeMeow(message: string) {
        this.onMeow.emit(`${this.catName} ${message}`);
    }
}

const myCat = new Cat('Tikki');

myCat.onMeow.subscribe(message => {
    // message is strongly-typed here;

    console.log(message); //-> Tikki cat is doing something
});

myCat.makeMeow('cat is doing something'); // send the event
```

Since you are sending the same type of event that differs only by the message, you would normally generalize it into a single event. That's why in the example I simplified it to just one event `onMeow`.

Also, `subscribe` is pretty much the standard approach today, which let's you easily cancel the subscription whenever you want, as shown below:

```
const sub = myCat.onMeow.subscribe(message => {
    console.log(message); // message is strongly-typed here;
});
```

When the event is no longer needed, you cancel the subscription:

```
sub.cancel();
```