# Typescript alias generic interface

Tags: typescript, class, types, interface, typescript-generics

I'm trying to take the following code for an event dispatcher, and make the types used (classes and interfaces) more specified.

- Note that I'm generally interested in understanding why my usage here with types/classes/interfaces/generic types here doesn't work, and less interested in events per se.

[Original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681315/3002584):

```
type Handler<E> = (event: E) => void;

class EventDispatcher<E> { 
    private handlers: Handler<E>[] = [];
    fire(event: E) { 
        for (let h of this.handlers)
            h(event);
    }
    register(handler: Handler<E>) { 
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to achieve:

- Use Typescript's `CustomEvent<any>` instead of `E`.
- Be able to define specific custom events that `extend`s `CustomEvent<any>`, for example:

  ```
  export class FormClearedEvent extends CustomEvent<any> {
     constructor() {
       super("formCleared");
     }
  }
  ```
- Export those specific custom event, together with the handler and the event dispacther

First attempt, doesn't compile:

```
export type Handler<CustomEvent<any>> = (event: CustomEvent<any>) => void;    // <-- doesn't compile
// Also, using CustomEvent<any> as the type parameter for the dispacther and its methods, doesn't compile as well.
```

Second attempt, makes me duplicate `SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>>` all over the place, *and* doesn't compile:

```
export type Handler<SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>> = (event: SpecificEvent) => void;
export class EventDispatcher<SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>> {
    private handlers: Handler<SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>>[] = []; // <-- doesn't compile
    fire(event: SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>) {                     // <-- doesn't compile
        for (let handler of this.handlers) {
            handler(event);
        }
    }
    register(handler: Handler<SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>>) {      // <-- doesn't compile
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}

// specific events
export class FormClearedEvent extends CustomEvent<any> {
   constructor() {
     super("formCleared");
   }
}
```

Third attempt, works, but now I have two classes which are really the same one (`CustomEvent<any>` and `SpecificEvent`):

```
// specific events
class SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any> { }
export class FormClearedEvent extends CustomEvent<any> {
   constructor() {
     super("formCleared");
   }
}

// SpecificEvent handler
export type Handler<SpecificEvent> = (event: SpecificEvent) => void;

// SpecificEvent dispatcher
export class EventDispatcher<SpecificEvent> {
    private handlers: Handler<SpecificEvent>[] = [];
    fire(event: SpecificEvent) {
        for (let handler of this.handlers) {
            handler(event);
        }
    }
    register(handler: Handler<SpecificEvent>) {
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```

My Question:

1. Why my first attempt doesn't compile?
2. Why some of the code in my second attempt doesn't compile?
3. Can I do better than the third way?

Answer (score 0):

Counter-intuitively, this might make more sense if we use less meaningful names.

In the first case, typescript is looking for something like this:

```js
export type Handler<T> = (event: T) => void;
```

We're trying to use `CustomEvent<any>` as the type parameter:

```js
export type Handler<CustomEvent<any>> = (event: CustomEvent<any>) => void;
```

-- which isn't a valid name. That explains why our second attempt gets past that; we've given it a valid name, `SpecificEvent`, and constrained it to extend `CustomEvent`:

```js
export type Handler<SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>> = (event: SpecificEvent) => void;
```

Similarly, now that we have a generic type named `SpecificEvent` in our class declaration:

```js
export class EventDispatcher<SpecificEvent extends CustomEvent<any>>
```

-- typescript thinks that the subsequent `extends` are going to be conditional types, and expects a question mark.

It looks like you can do something along these lines:

```js
export type Handler<E extends CustomEvent> = (event: E) => void;

export class EventDispatcher<E extends CustomEvent> {
  private handlers: Handler<E>[] = [];
  fire(event: E) {
    for (let handler of this.handlers) {
      handler(event);
    }
  }
  register(handler: Handler<E>) {
    this.handlers.push(handler);
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) But why `CustomEvent<any>`  is not valid in place of `T`? I thought `T` means anything, but it doesn't; specifically, it doesn't mean generic type, right? Can you link to some docs that specify that? (2) Why Typescript thinks it's a conditional type inside `class EventDispatcher` definition, but not inside `Handler` definition?